# Update data only if the letter is not in front

Tags: mysql, sql

My Data:

```
TAn
Ants
TAr
Arm
TogA
```

```
UPDATE sample SET sample_data = REPLACE(sample_data , 'A', 'a');
```

The above shows my data and the SQL code i am using to change A to a. However i only want to change A to a on if A is not the first letter. How can i accomplish this in MySQL?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: What if A is the first letter and also another letter, like `AbcA`? Should that stay the same or become `Abca`?

Comment: You'd probably use a regular expression to match a pattern like "any uppercase A that isn't at the beginning of the word", but this functionality doesn't exist as such in MySQL.  I  linked a duplicate that explains how you might do so.

Comment: is the data in separate rows or just in one? question's unclear on a few levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only call `REPLACE` on `SUBSTRING(sample_data, 2)`

```
UPDATE sample
SET sample_data = CONCAT(LEFT(sample_data, 1), REPLACE(SUBSTRING(sample_data, 2), 'A', 'a'))
```